# Use querySelector to get select based on two conditions, one being a prefix

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to select a div based on two conditions, one being a prefix.

So if I have

```
<div class="bob delay-10"></div>
<div class="joe delay-20"></div>
```

I want to have

```
function getdelay (classname) {
    let delayselect = document.querySelector("*[class='"+classname+"'], *[class*='delay-']");
return delayselect;
}
getdelay("joe");
```

should return `<div class="joe delay-20"></div>`

Currently the way it is working is it is selecting `OR` not `AND`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an actual class selector (`.`) for the fixed class name part.

```js
let delayselect = document.querySelector(`.${classname}[class*='delay-']`);
```

The backticks ("template literals") allow for simpler inclusion of expressions in strings.

Comment: `const getdelay = classname => document.querySelector(\`.${classname}[class*='delay-']\`);`